# Retrieving data from Firebase Swift to Tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

```html
{
  "Firebase" : {
    "AnotherTest" : "Test",
    "Class" : "Missed",
    "Owner" : "Lenovo",
    "Test" : "Folder"
  },
  "Posts" : {
    "-L0TR_W8Ao671XEGNY2O" : {
      "message" : "Message",
      "title" : "Title"
    }
  },
  "usersID" : {
    "SEdMgVirYTQ5x02BVP1a13oCu5n2" : {
      "info" : {
        "email" : "test@test.dk"
      }
    },
    "TcK0fcoRKxcOIlDBNrbGvpEN28H3" : {
      "class" : {
        "info" : "demo",
        "owner" : "airclass",
        "participant" : "ac-mobilie team",
        "time" : "15. dec @ 5:00 PM"
      },
      "info" : {
        "email" : "steen@steen.dk"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm kinda a newbie, and especially to Firebase :P
I'm trying to retrieve some data to a tableview, but i'm really struggling to get my snapshot to work, Can someone help?

[My codestring from X-code.][2]

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct postStruct {
    let title : String!
    let message : String!
}

class MissedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
let posts = [postStruct]()

var dbRef: DatabaseReference!

let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dbRef.child("Posts").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        //print("user data: \(value!)") //Dette er et JSON objekt oversat til et NSDictionary!

        let valueOfInfo = value?["Posts"] as? [String: Any]

        let title = "title: " + (valueOfInfo?["title"] as? String ?? "")
         let message = "message: " + (valueOfInfo?["message"] as? String ?? "")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    dbRef = Database.database().reference()
    post()
}


func post(){
    let title = "Title"
    let message = "Message"

    let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["title": title as AnyObject, "message": message as AnyObject]
    // Her siger man hvad man gerne vil have ind i databasen.

    dbRef.child("usersID").child(userID!).setValue(post) // Her indsætter man det på "usersID" række
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    // Her indsættes dataen i cellen.

    return cell

}


/*
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: some code would be helpful, we don't read minds..

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I'm so sorry and that makes perfect sense. Hope it's more convenient now and thanks in advance